# Is it possible to add a menu contribution for a XMLMultiPageEditorPart?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, e4

In the course of developing an Eclipse E4 plugin, I have a rather unusual issue. I added a menu contribution in fragment.xmi files, with the parent ID, **#AbstractTextEditorContext** and that seemed to reveal the menu contributions I have created for all text editors extending the AbstractTextEditor. The problem I have now is that I want to do the same for MultiPageEditor parts but can't seem to get it to work. I used plugin spy to get the active menu contribution identifier which seems to be **org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.editor** but setting it as the parent id does not reveal the menu contributions in the Eclipse XML editors. Any ideas are appreciated!

**EDIT**: Added the relevant xmi snippet

```
    <elements xsi:type="menu:MenuContribution" xmi:id="_a4MKwBmeEey64_O2FY8sFQ" elementId="com.example.menucontribution.addXmlReference" positionInParent="after=additions" parentId="org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.editor">
      <children xsi:type="menu:HandledMenuItem" xmi:id="_lUl4MBmeEey64_O2FY8sFQ" elementId="com.example.handledmenuitem.addRef" label="Add reference" tooltip="Add work ref" command="_V06J8E1BEeufD9mwn57rfw"/>
      <children xsi:type="menu:HandledMenuItem" xmi:id="_lo4GIBmeEey64_O2FY8sFQ" elementId="com.example.handledmenuitem.viewref" label="View references" tooltip="View ref" command="_EHEzYFWeEeuRq6eENV2SgQ"/>
    </elements>
```

Comment: Source code for the editor is [here](https://git.eclipse.org/c/sourceediting/webtools.sourceediting.git/tree/xml/bundles/org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui/src-multipage/org/eclipse/wst/xml/ui/internal/tabletree/XMLMultiPageEditorPart.java). That does appear to be the correct menu id. What are you using for the position - "additions" looks like the only valid position.

Comment: I've added the xmi snippet to the question as well now. The position is set to additions (after to be precise) as well.